# QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice - PyQt4 in Spyder

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I know there are several posts related to this issue but I couldn't find a working solution for my script. I tried adding some if **name** == '**main**' but I actually don't understand where is the problem.

The thing is that the script works the first time I run it. But the second time the IPython kernel crashes, so I have to restart a new kernel each time.
I am using this script to control a USB analogic device via a GUI with Python 2.7 64-bits and PyQT4, in the editor Spyder on a windows machine.
Thanks a lot.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys
import USB3101 as U 


def FromSlider(VChan, Box):
    Slider = Window.sender() 
    Percentage = Slider.value()
    U.SetPower(VChan,Percentage)
    Box.setValue(Percentage)

def FromBox(VChan, Slider):
    Box = Window.sender()
    Percentage = Box.value()
    U.SetPower(VChan,Percentage)
    Slider.setValue(Percentage)

app    = QApplication(sys.argv)
Window = QWidget()

Slider = QSlider(Qt.Vertical)
Slider.setMinimum = 0
Slider.setMaximum = 100
Slider.valueChanged.connect(lambda : FromSlider(U.VChan1,Box))

Box = QSpinBox()
Box.valueChanged.connect(lambda : FromBox(U.VChan1,Slider))
Box.setMinimum(0)
Box.setMaximum(100)

Layout = QVBoxLayout()
Layout.addWidget(Slider)
Layout.addWidget(Box)
Window.setLayout(Layout)

Window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well by setting in the parameters to execute the scrit in a dedicated Python console I don't crash the kernel each time I relaunch the script.